# HTTP requests and Cookies (HTTP Client) - How do I manipulate them in a desktop app?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, cookies, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have just started to learn C# and Asp.Net and I have a specific project in mind but I need to be able to manipulate cookies client side and I can't find good documentation for this so I decided to ask for help to get a starting point.
I want to make a desktop application that is a little to complex for my actual knowledge but I need a starting point: I need to be able to load a list of usernames and passwords and proxies and proxyuser and proxy pass. This little part of the application will use the accounts and proxies to login to a webpage using httpclient. When I send a GET request to the login page I get back a response that contain some hidden parameters that I must assign to some variables and a cookie. I don't know how to save that cookie in a location that I choose (the application folder under the "cookies" folder) with the name that I choose (the username used for login should be the name of that cookie). After I sort thru the response I have to send a POST request to the server with all the hidden parameters and the user and pass parameters and the cookie. The server will send back a response with another cookie that I want to save in the same location as the first one with the same name (overwritten ). This cookie will be used later in the program to do other actions on that server under that login. All this requests must use a certain proxy with its credentials, proxy that will change every time I use a new login.
I managed to find out how to use the HTTP Client from Asp.Net Web API to send the get req or to post but I have no idea how to get such a control over cookies that the site want to store on my computer and how to use different private proxies for each login... I did all the above using PHP and CURL and is very easy to control the cookies using cURL but I need to do it in C# and make a desktop app so ... Asp.Net Web API and HTTP Client is the key I think...
Please give me a hand to start my project and don't dismiss my question just because I'm to noob with .net or c#  :)
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Get this library http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Create an instance of HttpClientHandler.  It has a CookieContainer property.  You can set all the cookies you want in there.

Create an instances of HttpClient as pass the HttpClientHandler instance into the constructor.

All HTTP requests you make with HttpClient will now have the cookies attached.

Comment: As I remember reading on MSDN the cookies are stored in the same location where internet explorer store cookies but I want to be able to store the cookies in a folder that I choose in the program (hard coded, not an option for the user). Also, how do I use private proxies to send and receive requests and responses? (not the proxy that internet explorer uses but proxies that my application will load)

Comment: @Florin You can set the Cookie header directly and manage it all yourself.  You can derive from DelegatingHandler to act as a kind of in-process proxy.  Not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I try to make an application that (as a first step) will use a list of private proxies (with user and pass) and a list of accounts (username and password) to login to youtube one by one (and do other things on youtube once they are logged in).For that I need to be able to control the cookies or else Google will know that is a software doing automated actions on their site and not a real person. So all the actions of one account should be under one proxy then I need to change the proxy when another account is used and so on.